# JSF xmlns URI not registered in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, xhtml

Here is the start of my JSF file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
```

However, `http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components` and `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` are highlighted in red with error `URI is not registered`. This causes many other subsequent tags to appear in red with errors `element 'x' is not allowed here`. Here is an image showing what I mean:

[image: xmlns and tags appear in red]

### Attempted solutions:

When searching for a solution, it appeared some others with the same problem solved it by doing "Fetch External Resource". However, this didn't work for me. For the icefaces xmlns `xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"` I get the error: `Error while fetching http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components`. And for the jstl xmlns `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"` I get the error: `No XML at the location: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`.

I also found some people solved it by deleting the IntelliJ IDEA metadata file `workspace.xml` in the `.idea` directory. This does seem to work temporarily... but then it seems the problem comes back after a while. I also have to reconfigure several project settings which I would like to avoid.

Any help would be appreciated.. I'm not really familiar with the xmlns stuff and still a beginner to web app development. Thank you!

### Update:

As per Mark Vedder's answer, I manually added external resources to my project and the problem has not resurfaced thus far.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With unregistered resources, the first solution is to use the "Fetch External Resource" quickfix. If that fails, as it has for you in this case, (usually because the "location" is in name only) you need to manually configure it.

**To Manually Configure**

1. If the resource (i.e.  the `.xsd`, `.dtd`, etc.) exists in one of your library jars, skip to step 2. Otherwise, download a copy of the resource. Put it somewhere convenient on your system.
2. In IDEA, with your cursor on the error, open the Quick Fix / Intentions menu by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select "Manually Setup External Resource". (If you do not have this option (based on IntelliJ IDEA version) go to the next section for instructions.)
3. If the resource is in a jar, select the `Schemas` tab and select the resource from the appropriate jar. If you downloaded it, select the `Explorer` tab (may be named Finder in Mac) and navigate to and select the file you downloaded.
4. Click OK and let IDEA index the resource.

**To Edit or Set via IDE Settings**

1. Open the settings Dialog via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or *File > Settings.*

   - To configure for all future new projects so this schema is avaiable, open the similar dialog via *File > Other Settings > Default Settings*
2. In the `Project Settings` section, find the `Schemas and DTDs` node.
3. Configure the desired schema. There are add, edit and delete icons in the upper right. Like above, you can select a file within a library via the `Schemas` tab, or your file system via the `Explorer` tab.

**UPDATE**

The various JSF Taglib definitions (for JSF 2.x and above) can be found in the `com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib` directory of the `com.sun.faces:jsf-impl` jar. The `jsf-impl` JAR file can be downloaded from [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg:%22com.sun.faces%22%20AND%20a:%22jsf-impl%22) among other places.

Comment: Ok, it seems the problem went away again since reloading my project. I was able to add an external resource according to your instructions though and the problem didn't resurface at least for now. So I will upvote your solution, and accept it if it doesn't reappear within the next couple of hours. Also, I'll add an update about this into the tried solutions part of my question.

Comment: In IDEA Community Edition 14.0.2 instead of Project Seetings one can find Languages & Frameworks.

Comment: Tried com.sun.faces:jsf-impl 2.2.20 (latest), which does not contain XSD for the URI: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html. It contains XmlFile:default.dtd,
XmlFile:facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd, mlFile:javaee_web_services_client_1_4.xsd, mlFile:web-facesconfig_1_0.dtd,
XmlFile:web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd,
XmlFile:web-facesuicomponent_2_0.xsd

Answer (score 24):

A probable issue could be that the "Java EE: Java Server Faces" plugin is disabled. You can enable it by browsing to 
**Settings > Plugins** and on the **Installed tab** search for **Java Server Faces**.

Comment: it is Jakarta EE: Server Faces (JSF) as of June 2022

Answer (score 4):

I tried every thing suggested here to get intellij to recognize the correct version of my jsf. At the end I discovered that I didn't have a direct reference in my web project maven dependencies to jsf-api. In other words, adding

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.29-08</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to my pom, fixed it. The confusing thing is that intellij was able to resolve a subset of the jsf symbols, which makes you think that the jar was being seen by it, albeit a wrong version of the jar.

Answer (score 4):

In IntellijIDEA 2022 we need to add Plugin Jakarta EE: ServerFaces(JSF)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Roberto, thx for the tip, it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "IntelliJ Idea", please open the "Project Structure" dialog by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, look for the `JSF not found` in the artifact (some thing like that) error notification, please click the fix it option and change the JSF scope to `provided`. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you do not attach the library of JSF Mojarro. Download and add that library in the project.

```
File> Project Structure> Library
```

add JSF the library.

Comment: Thx it resolve the problem for me. (I added the jsf dependency in maven)

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue with icefaces resources.
One way to fix this is to give the project (again, if you already did not) the IceFaces framework support (right click on project name).
In my case I was using 3.3.0, then I set download in the Add Framework Support form.
Intellij downloaded 3.1.0 and the IDE recognizes the resource immediately after. Later I set again the 3.3.0 version.
So, I think is enough to re download the framework again, and the resources will be downloaded in META-INF folder.
Regards.-

Answer (score 0):

you could also add `"urn:import:<url>"`

example:
     `xmlns:d="urn:import:com.mypackage.mylovelycode"`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue... but in my case, the problem was that by mistake I saved file with extension ".xml". Changing it into ".xhtml" solved the problem