# Why are primefaces-Tags highlighted as error in IntelliJ?

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, primefaces, xhtml

I have xhtml-files in my spring-project. In IntelliJ it suggests me some imports like `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` when I use primefaces-Tags. But when I agree the import the URI is also highlighted as ERROR with message "URI is not registered".

Below a snippet from a xhtml-file:

```
  <p:column headerText="Username"
          <h:outputText value="#{user.username}"/>
  </p:column>
```

`<p>` and `<h>` are highlighted in colors, but in `<p:column>` or `<h:outputText>` the string after the colon is always highlighted as ERROR with message, e.g. "cannot resolve symbol h:outputText".

The strange thing is, the project compiles with no errors. But in IntelliJ the whole xhtml-files are full of "errors". It's quite annoying when looking for an error and all the lines are RED.

I've already tried to "Invalidate cache/restart".

Hope someone can help me solving this problem?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/23412539/104891.

Comment: add `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`

Comment: @YagamiLight I've already added this line .. above was just an example .. no line like this works

Comment: Have you checked if JSF support is enabled in intelliJ? follow this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/preparing-for-jsf-application-development.html

Comment: yes it is .. I use the ultimate edition .. i already solved the problem .. i had wrong parameters in the <!DOCTYPE> tag